# как по-другому можно написать код? Числа Фибоначчи

Tags: c++, числа-фибоначчи

```
int Fib(int i) {
  int val = 0;
  if (i < 1) return 0;
  if (i == 1) return 1;
  return Fib(i - 1) + Fib(i - 2);
}
int main() {
   int i = 0;
   while (true) {
      cout << Fib(i) << endl;
      i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: А что не так с этими вариантом?

Comment: [Мемоизацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Мемоизация) прикрутить для эффективности. [тыц](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47457462/5045688)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(unsigned long long f0 = 0, f1 = 1; f0 <= f1; f1 += f0, f0 = f1-f0)
        cout << f1 << endl;
}
```

P.S. И попробуйте только написать, что требуется именно функция или именно рекурсия - в условии этого нет, а вывод именно тот, что вам нужен. Разве что вовремя обрывается :)